# Required field after checkbox is marked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I'm very new to JavScript and am I'm trying to create a form that requires information be input into a field after a checkbox is marked, by toggling a required class. 
I've tried for two days and am unable to make the "Start Date" a required field if the "Gymnasium" box is checked.
Any help would be great.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#gym").change(function(){              
            $("#togg1").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#startDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#endDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#startTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#endTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#startDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#endDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#startTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#endTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#startDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#endDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#startTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#endTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });

    </script>


    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="courseForm" style="width: 500px; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 50px 0 50px 50px;margin: 0 auto;">
    <form id="serviceForm" action="#" onSubmit="required(this);" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
    <input name="orgid" type="hidden" value="000001" />
    <input name="retURL" type="hidden" value="#" />
    <label for="company">* Agency Requesting Facility:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="company" required="required" maxlength="50" name="company" size="50" type="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="name">* Agency Contact:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="name" required="required" maxlength="50" name="name" size="50" type="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="phone">* Contact Phone Number:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="phone" required="required" maxlength="14" name="phone" size="14" type="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />Courses offered
    <br />

<input id="gym" name="gym" type="checkbox" value="1" />Gymnasium
    <br />
    <span id="togg1" style="display:none">
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline">
                <lable for="startDate">* Start Date:</lable>
                    <input id="startDate" maxlength="10" name="startDate" size="10" />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline">
                <lable for="endDate">* End Date:</lable>
                    <input id="endDate" maxlength="10" name="endDate" size="10" /><br /><br />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline">
                <lable for="startTime">* Start Time:</lable>
                    <input for="startTime" maxlength="7" name="startTime" size="7" />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline">
                <lable for="endTime">* End Time:</lable>
                    <input for="endTime" maxlength="7" mane="endTime" size="7" /><br />
            </span>
    </span>

    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="description">Comments:</label>
    <br />
    <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />* denotes required fields
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer and given a jsfiddle, I think the solution is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add 'required' attribute to 'Start Date'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#gym").change(function(){              
      $("#togg1").toggle(this.checked);
      $("#startDate").toggleClass("required");

      if(this.checked){
           $("#startDate").attr('required','required');
      }else{
           $("#startDate").removeAttr('required')
      }

   });
});
```

Comment: This worked great. I've changed my initial post to reflect the changes. I'm trying to implement this into 4 fields but the time fields don't work. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your original question is answered. This is entirely new problem.In such scenarios post it as separate question. . The problem with is 'id' is same for all the input elements. Read a bit about how jquery selectors work.

Comment: Oh, I had the input for time set as "for" not "id".

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You call a function "required" in the "onSubmit". This is not neccessary and wrong because the "required" function does not exist.

Then, you have to add the following line:

```
$("#serviceForm").validate();
```

In a "$(document).ready" call so that it is executed after DOM has loaded.

Here you have an example of how it would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rscN/

I have supposed you use the following plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

If not, you have to add it.

For the validate plugin, I think you have to use the required class, not the required attribute. You are mixing class required with the attribute required, which is an attribute you can use in HTML5, but always take into account not all browsers support it.

For a good reference about this:

http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was unable to get it to work, but will use it in the future.